# chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data

Tags: centos, nginx

I am trying to install laravel , now I need to Set the required permissions for the project . when I wrote `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel/` I am getting error `chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’` .What is the problem?

Comment: It clearly states what the problem is so what are you confused about?

Comment: I am using nginx not apache .can I write  sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/laravel is the same thing?

Comment: You will have to check how your system is setup and what users actually exist. For example do a `ls -la /var` and look what user and group is set for the www directory, check your service configuration, `htop` or your passwd file.

Comment: I checked   etc/passwd  nginx:x:998:996:nginx user:/var/cache/nginx: this line exist .

Comment: In that case you could try our suggestion. The target of the `chown` command is to make the file owned by the user and group the webserver uses.

Answer (score 2):

The www-data is for ubuntu, try with apache for username and group

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/laravel/
```

Make sure that the package is install.

Comment: sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/laravel/ is that okey?

Comment: Yes run with that, i don't know you have nginx